# Getting the last modified user of a Revision Drive SDK v3

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I'm trying to get the last modified user of a Revision using C#.

Whenever I try and get the lastmodifieduser from the Revision object, I end up with a null pointer.

```
User driveuser;
foreach (string fileid in fileids)
  {
      revisionRequest = service.Revisions.List(fileid);
      revisionRequest.PageSize = 1;
    try
    {
        revisions = revisionRequest.Execute().Revisions;
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        continue;
    }
    if(revisions != null && revisions.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var revision in revisions)
        {
            driveuser = revision.lastmodifyinguser;
        }
    }

    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No revisions");
    }
      user = null;
      revisions.Clear();
```

I end up with driveuser being null. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok so I tried the request on the Drive API website, and the requests I'm sending aren't giving me all the metadata I need, only the id, kind, modified type etc. Why is this?

Comment: Try adding "fields=*" or "fields=lastModifyingUser" to the request

Answer (score 0):

Pinoyyid's solution worked, I had to add the fields I wanted using revisionRequest.Fields